# How to generate report for the volume in splunk?

Tags: report, volume, splunk

I need to generate the report of Heavy forwarder migrations based on volume of load. Run a query in splunk for host= in the below format
indices, volume. HF name

I am using a tstats search query for that getting the HF name and indices but not able to get the volume

My question is how to generate the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Depending the data you want, you may be able to find it in the internal index.

```
index=_internal component=metrics group=tcpin_connections
| stats sum(kb) as Kb by sourceHost
```

This search will provide the volume of data received from each host.  It's not clear, however, if "host" means HF or originating host.  I suspect it's the latter, but don't have an HF in my sandbox to test with.

Comment: Thanks RichG. My issue got resolved with your help.